# Android - what should be the ActionbarSherlock style configuration?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I have 3 styles.xml files in these folders:

res/values:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

res/values-v11

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

res/values-v14

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Is it right to have v11 and v14 to have Holo.Light as the config? And then to have Theme.Sherlock.Light as the default?

I am testing on a v-11 emulator, and I had to add this line to my code:

```
setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light);
```

But I am not sure if it will work for all necessary versions. Is this the correct setup? Or do I need to adjust something? I am a bit confused why I had to specify the theme in the code if it is already specified in the xml.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 6):

If I have not misunderstood your doubts:

Sherlock is a port of the android ActionBar for older devices. So if you are using Sherlock you can get the same `android:Theme.Holo.Light` style for both (older and newer devices). If you wanto the style to be applyed on older devices you have to remove the `android:` prefix

this way you will have the same looks for older and newer device

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

So you can keep on `style` file, and if you need to have different customization on tablet and  handset, you can customize the `dimens` and `colors` file

Comment: Thank you. My concern was also just to double check that the current configuration I showed is the rigth way to do things. I just wasn't sure. Is it right to configure the Holo.Light and Sherlock.Light as I did there?

Comment: you can configure only sherlock to get the same look of Holo.Light and ger rid of the others styles.xml file

Comment: interesting. So I only need the one styles.xml file? And the v-11 and v-14 folders would not have a styles.xml at all? Is that how it might be better?

Comment: imo yes it is. I usally used this way for both handset and tablet

Comment: I get: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowBackground'.

Comment: @UrielFrankel try adding tools:ignore="NewApi" in the item without the android prefix

Comment: I have added  tools:ignore="NewApi" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" and it doesnt work. I think they changed something in the ABS that makes this error. is it right?

Answer (score 1):

By default ActionBar Sherlock will be like this and it is compatible with every version.

In Styles:

```
  <style name="ExampleTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/new_indicator</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/new_indicator</item>
</style>
```

In v11

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light" />
```

In v14

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" />
```

and in the manifest file it will be declared as

```
android:theme="@style/ExampleTheme" >
```

So I can say that it takes values-styles by default for every android version. No need to care about v11 and v14.